# PHP: file_get_contents a PHP file with include();

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

I have a PHP Script that calls a master PHP template (acts as HTML template) with `file_get_contents`, replaces a few words from it and then saves the final file as another PHP in a directory.

But the master PHP template itself has `include();` and `require_once();` in it and the saved file after replacing the words doesn't load the files called from the master template.

The HTML source code of the saved file is with `<?php include('file_here'); ?>` in it, but not with the output of file_here -- see image.

[image]

How can I call file_get_contents(); and still let the master template execute include(); or require_once(); ?

Comment: Your best bet here is to include the master template file as well, maybe within a ob_start/ob_get_clean block and do your replacements on the results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` will get the content of a file, not execute it as a PHP script. If you want this piece of code to be executed, you need to either include it, or process it (through an HTTP request to Apache, for instance).

If you include this file, it'll be processed as PHP code, and of course, print your HTML tags (`include*` can take any kind of file).

If you need to work with its content before you print it, use `ob_*` functions to manipulate the PHP output buffer. See : https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

```
ob_start(); // Start output buffer capture.
include("yourtemplate.php"); // Include your template.
$output = ob_get_contents(); // This contains the output of yourtemplate.php
// Manipulate $output...
ob_end_clean(); // Clear the buffer.
echo $output; // Print everything.
```

By the way, such mechanism sounds heavy for a template engine. Basically, templates should not contain PHP code. If you want such behavior, have a look at Twig : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/